# Query string in php code

Tags: php, variables, get, query-string

How to put the querystring name in php?

```
$file_get_html('http://localhost/search/?q=');
```

And when accessing localhost/`?name=example` the code looks like this

```
$file_get_html('http://localhost/search/?q=example');
```

I do not know how to put `$_GET['url']` inside a php :(

Comment: file_get_html($_GET['url']); - if that's really what you mean.

Comment: There's no `$` before `file_get_html`

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Are you trying to merge the query string you received with some other URL?

Comment: I am not following what you want.  What does a parameter of `URL` have to do with the parameter `q` that you are showing?  can you better explain what is is you are trying to do?

Comment: `<?php
// setup
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
// get DOM from URL or file
$html = $file_get_html('http://localhost/serarch/?q=');
?>`

Wanna use the Simple HTML DOM Parser to extract data of a page. However, this page is a result of seek. So, I replace the variable in my url, the site url [search].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't very clear, but I suspect this is the answer:

```
file_get_html('http://localhost/search/?q=' . urlencode($_GET['url']));
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: file_get_html in C:\_server\htdocs\test.php on line 7

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\_server\htdocs\test.php on line 7

line 7: `$html = $file_get_html('http://localhost/bsearch/?q=' . urlencode($_GET['movie']));`

Comment: Didn't you see the comment I wrote an hour ago? There shouldn't be a `$` before `file_get_html()`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Worked. I thought the `$` in front of `file_get_html` was standard for extension

Comment: `$` is for variables in PHP, I don't know where you got the idea it had anything to do with extensions.

Comment: Although I know very little PHP, I know that the `$` is all PHP variables. However, I thought it was necessary for the extension to work `$`. Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The ?q=example will let you use something like $example = $_GET['q'],
and $example should equal the value of q in your querystring.

If you have a querystring that looks like this:

```
?q=example&url=myurl.com
```

You can access the q and url parameters like this:

```
$q = $_GET['q']; // which will equal 'example'
$url = $_GET['url']; // which will equal 'myurl.com'
```

If that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: But how to put in `$file_get_html`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = urlencode($_GET['url']);
$contents = file_get_contents("http://localhost/search/?q={$url}");

var_dump($contents);
```